# Feasibility and effectiveness of a Gravity Hammer?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons, science-fiction, gravity

A well-known weapon in the world of Halo, the [Gravity Hammer](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Type-2_Energy_Weapon/Hammer). It seems to be able to manipulate the forces of gravity to produce a really really nasty blow often to comedic results launching people in armor suits weighing at 1000 pounds(453.6 kilograms) and armored vehicles across the battlefield[and a real excellent job at smashing them].

How would such a weapon work? Is it feasible to build such a weapon in real life? How effective would it be if it were used against medieval targets/Knights? (I still think you would get shot to pieces if you tried charge at someone with a firearm)

Comment: Everything that change gravity is unfeasible.

Comment: How exactly is manipulating gravity meant to improve the weapon's blow? Is it pushing the target or is it manipulating the mass of the hammer? If the hammer was made momentarily very heavy, in a way that it could still be handled by the user, it would nonetheless lose its useful momentum mid-swing. If it's just pushing the target by changing how gravity affects it, maybe they experience G-force, but where is the blow?

Comment: Could it work by using gravity to accelerate the blow?

Comment: I'm not a genius at physics and I have no idea how such a weapon would work anyway.

Comment: @Planarian that makes sense, if we're treating the mechanism kind of nebulously here. I could also be wrong about my momentum thing, I'm just assuming that if you made it very heavy it would slow down so as to conserve momentum (mass * velocity). But if we've got a gravity field manipulator, this could be free energy, so maybe the hammer keeps swinging as fast as it was and now it just weighs as much as a house.

Comment: @RossC Ow. But then free energy isn't a thing so maybe it can somehow accumulate a ton of gravitational potential energy?

Comment: @Planarian, Yes, that would also work, but in the game it's kind of shown that you can swing it this way and that, and if you want to send your enemy flying, you can't come down on his head. In a realistic sense, outside the context of the game, you could increase the "weight" of the hammer (the gravity experienced by the hammer) but you'd have to bring it down on your enemy's head.

Comment: @RossC Actually I would assume that OP doesn't need them to fly. It's just game rag doll physics. And bringing a house down on someone would be guaranteed kill

Comment: So you have super advanced tech and are trying to design a convoluted and impractical weapon to fight medieval knights. Why not use a real practical weapon. What is the purpose of such a hard to build weapon. A few drones would be much easier and more effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, the Weapon is Not Feasible in Real Life**

The short story is that any machine that affects gravity on a macro level is simply not feasible.  Well, excepting perhaps the case where a very large machine were to be made in space, at which point it may have enough microgravity to help trap some dust... but that's purely a function of the amount of material in the machine, not what it does.

We don't conclusively know how gravity works now for any other answer to be possible.

At best, if gravitons were real it could perhaps create gravitons and/or anti-gravitons, but doing so would require so much energy and take up so much space* that it couldn't possibly fit into something roughly the size of a large axe.

*To clarify the space comment, consider this: to create gravitons/manipulate a gravity field on a macro level the device would undoubtedly consume significant energy.  Just to create some particles today we require the momentary output of an entire power plant... and that's just a few particles.  For the sheer amount of manipulation that would be necessary the power requirements would be astronomical.  Storing that much power would take a lot of area... not just a a slot for a few D-cell batteries (which is about the best-case scenario for what would fit in the axe).

**Update: Additional Note**

Another reason this is not possible/feasible is that gravity cannot be manipulated in only one direction.  If you were to increase the gravitational attraction to something (or reverse it, somehow) that effect would ripple out in a complete sphere from the device itself.  So not only would your opponent be pushed/pulled, you would be too.  It's hard to see how a melee weapon that smashes your face into the blade or throws itself from your hands could ever be effective (though it looks hilarious when I imagine the result).

Comment: ...and now I have an image of a knight binding his sword to his hand and flying around the battlefield with it leading the way.

Comment: Amazing, smashing your own face and your enemies. It's killing 2 birds with one stone...

Answer (score 1):

### We don't have the knowledge to manipulate gravity, and I don't think it's possible

High mass elements create more gravity, that being said, even if we manage to figure out *how to push a hammer with gravity force*, the gravity of the planet you are on will just overwrite it.

Gravity is a very complex force, it's not linear and apparently the only way to create it, it's by having an enormous mass, you don't just have to be big, you need mass.

So let's say with create a hammer with a lot of mass, you wouldn't be able to hold it.

Now, also imagine you hit the car with the hammer, as old Newton said *every force creates a reaction*, you will be throw in the air as well.

### May be…

A hammer with a *propulsor on the edge*, I mean, a kind of like a impulsor that when it hits a target activates, but again, talking in the actual world, if you don't have the strength to hold the reaction, you will get recoil, just like any other weapon. Or in the other edge! A propulsor that boost the hammer swing. Now, if you miss, it would definitely hurt.

I don't think is possible to do just use gravity nor use a somehow propulsor *(as spaceships, but of course much more smaller in every aspect)*, but I'm not sure on the second one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that there is a format button for **headers** in the editing toolbar. You can even make different levels of header, which work nicely withnthe page’s CSS. So don’t fake them with an all bold paragraph.