# Would a sonic sword be useful in the middle ages?

Tags: warfare, weapons, medieval

Say Mongolian armies managed to forge a sonic saber to conquer Europe, the only handwavium part of the story is the special blade only responds to its master and when connecting with an opponents melee weapon, the blade immediately reacts, generating an ultrasonic frequency through the metal.

Would such an ability be helpful for the Mongolian army, please focus on the abilities of the weapon itself, rather than different types of melee weapons.

This question is entirely about the advantages of the weapon which had been granted as a one time miracle exception of the rules of nature, you may use their unique fighting style or combat strategy based on experiences (historic records) to highlight the pros and cons of swinging a sonic sword.

For this question assume the finest crucible steel is used and I'll leave it to your discretion how a piece of steel undergoes such stress.

Comment: Why do the Mongolian need a special sword?  If their Khans hadn't been alcoholic die-too-earlies, they would have cleaned absolutely everyone's clocks.

Comment: This kind of reminds me of the [Gravity Hammer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54609/feasibility-and-effectiveness-of-a-gravity-hammer) question, and has about the same answer.  The effect would impact the wielder of the weapon more than the target, as the wielder is closer and in constant contact with the weapon.

Comment: Contrary to what you see in movies, warfare is about tried and true methods rather than flashy gadgets. A mechanically complex melee weapon that is questionably better in certain situations would be quickly discarded in favor of the basic sword and spear.

Answer (score 9):

Sound waves are vibration. So your sword now vibrates 'ultrasonic'-ly. Kind of like an orbital sander, I guess.

Have you ever held an orbital sander for an hour? It will make your hand go numb. It is probably dis-advantageous in general to hold a sword that makes your hand go numb half-way through battle.

You may also notice that between an orbital sander and a sword, most people would consider the sword to be the better melee weapon (possible exception: Jackie Chan).

An orbital sander doesn't do 'sonic' damage to anyone, but is still hard to hold for a long time. I imagine an orbital sander putting out enough vibrational energy to harm someone would harm the holder first, since he's the closest to it. Not to mention, that would make it REALLY hard to hold.

All in all, a vibrating sword seems like a real waste of vibrating magic.

Answer (score 2):

If you had selected any other empire for this question, the answer would be different.

> Would such an ability be helpful for the **Mongolian army**, please focus on the abilities of the weapon itself, rather than different types of melee weapons.

Mongolians values speed and mobility..they are famed horse archers and renowned for explosive technologies and siege well before their time.  They practices archery and horse riding for the majority of their lifetime, not sword training (easily noted by their inferior sword skills in the face of a practiced swordsmen such as the Japanese samurai).  The sword was a fallback weapon for the mongols, not the primary weapon of war.

This makes a second piece of handwavium come up...why would the mongols forge this?  It's comparable to the American Marines producing an unobtainium knife and neglecting their rifle.

kk...lets say for whatever reason the Mongols favoured their sword.  Their empire is beyond massive and speed is still at the core of it.  The mongol favoured sword was a curved scimitar designed primarily for use from horseback in ride by attack format (not suitable to sonic as listed in the question as blade on blade either doesn't happen in this format or is very brief contact).

The sonic factor of your weapon (and the heart of your question) is pretty irrelevant as you've chosen one of the few medieval empires that don't depend on swordsmanship.